# Dynamic programming. 4xn matrix, how to find max sum in O(n)

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have few restrictions. I can`t pick values from cells that share side (diagonal is ok). I can pick multiple elements from each column.

For example. I have a matrix

```
1 3 6 10 3
4 2 6 7  9
5 1 8 3  3
9 2 9 1  1
```

If I pick 1 and 5, in first I have to pick 2 and 2 in second, 6 and 8 in third and so on.

Best I can come up with is brute forcing the algorithm, but that is O(n^4) any ideas?
I have looked at Hungarian algorithm but it does not work in O(n) as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is restricted to `4 × n`, we can just run a dynamic program. Assuming our choices for any column can be only one of:

```
a) x  b) -  c) -  d) -
   -     x     -     -
   -     -     x     -
   -     -     -     x

e) x  f) -  g) x  h) -
   -     x     -     -
   x     -     -     -
   -     x     x     -
```

We can define `f(i, p)` to represent the maximum sum up to and including the `i`th column when we choose pattern `p` for our element selections. Then:

```
f(i, a) = sum ith column elements pattern a + max(
  f(i - 1, b),
  f(i - 1, c),
  f(i - 1, d),
  f(i - 1, f),
  f(i - 1, h)
)

f(i, b) = sum ith column elements pattern b + max(
  f(i - 1, a),
  f(i - 1, c),
  f(i - 1, d),
  f(i - 1, e),
  f(i - 1, g),
  f(i - 1, h)
)

etc.
```

Since `p` is restricted to 8 choices, the search space is `O(n * 8) = O(n)`.